# Service not running application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, process

I am creating a service which runs an .exe file on Windows 7. It must be done as a service due to complex requirements, so a console application is not possible.

I have written the following code, which works perfectly in a console application, however when placed in the service, the executable is never run.

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    try
    {
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Folder";
        startInfo.FileName = "MyApp.exe";
        Process myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

No errors are being thrown, but the application is simply not starting.

I have read that services cannot run an executable in a straightforward manner, and have modified the above code based on suggestions, however it does not work.

**EDIT: I have configured the service manually as follows:**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to specify concrete user to run under in service properties dialog?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot showing what I have configured in the services window.

Comment: So, this user can have insufficent rights to run external apps. Try to dig info in user politics or run under 'administrator' (but this is a bad idea).

Comment: The user has enough rights, as when opening an executable manually through the administrator command line, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been the cause of great frustration, and I have finally solved my problem. Yes, I have managed to make a service load a GUI application, even though everyone says that it is impossible. There is a warning though - the "fix" can be considered as exploiting a loophole in Windows, as the code which I used basically passes the Vista and Windows 7 UAC. Essentially, the application is always executed with full rights and bypasses the UAC.

If anyone has this same problem, what you need to do is iterate through a list of logged in users on the PC, and choose to open the UI application in this session (which has the user's desktop), rather than in session 0 where the service is supposed to be running (and which does not have a desktop).

For some people, this might not be a solution as it is not secure. But in my case, security is not a main concern, and I just needed it to work (had to be a service by force).

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem that I had.