# Unable to load executable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, process

I'm attempting to create a service which opens an application, however I have had no luck. Thus, I downloaded the following sample code, and attempted to create a service based on it. However, it does not work either. What happens is that the code executes, however the executable is never called (in the following case, the calculator is not opened).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Open_Calculator
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public static Process process;
        public Service1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            string[] args = { "1", "2" };
            OnStart(args);
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            start_calc();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
        static protected void start_calc()
        {
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The same exact code copy-pasted in a console application works.

The service is set to interact with the desktop, and it is set to run as "LocalSystem".

The account running the service does have access to `C:\Windows\System32` as I tested it. Process.Start() does not return any errors, and calc is not running in the background (checked through task manager)

Comment: Does the account that runs the service have access to `C:\Windows\System32`? Does `process.Start()` produce an error? Have you verified that calc isn't running in the background (using Task Manager and checking "Show processes from all users")?

Comment: The account running the service does have access to `C:\Windows\System32` as I tested it. Process.Start() does not return any errors, and calc is not running in the background (checked through task manager)

Comment: Maybe you have to enable "service can interact with desktop" in the service properties? Normally, a service is not allowed to show a gui, this could also apply to child processes.

Comment: @PMF As described in my question, I have that checkbox enabled :/

Comment: Oh, overlooked that...

Comment: Have you tried just creating a console app and copying and pasting your start_calc function into that? At least you'd be able to isolate whether it's service related or if your code is the problem.

Comment: @Pete - yes, it works fine in a console application. Issue is only in a service

Comment: Is the `Interactive Services Detection` service running?

Comment: @Pete - I enabled it, and the calculator does show. But only after a message appearing, asking the user if he would like to "view a message" from the service. When choosing "yes", it opens a full-screen application which contains the calculator inside it.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Service not running application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000995/service-not-running-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been the cause of great frustration, and I have finally solved my problem. Yes, I have managed to make a service load a GUI application, even though everyone says that it is impossible. There is a warning though - the "fix" can be considered as exploiting a loophole in Windows, as the code which I used basically passes the Vista and Windows 7 UAC. Essentially, the application is always executed with full rights and bypasses the UAC.

If anyone has this same problem, what you need to do is iterate through a list of logged in users on the PC, and choose to open the UI application in this session (which has the user's desktop), rather than in session 0 where the service is supposed to be running (and which does not have a desktop).

For some people, this might not be a solution as it is not secure. But in my case, security is not a main concern, and I just needed it to work (had to be a service by force).

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem that I had.

Answer (score 0):

Execute it with "Run as administrator" permission

Comment: This isnt the issue, I'm running with an administrator account